# Is there a stemmer for elasticsearch that can change "broken" to "break"

Tags: elasticsearch, stemming

Here is what I'd like the stemmer to do:
breaking: break
broke: break
broken: break
entering: enter
entered: enter
enter: enter

I've indexed the field as follows:
              "body": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "stemmed": { 
                    "type":     "text",
                    "analyzer": "english"
                  }
                }
              }

When I query “breaking and entering”, I can see that what is searched for in the body.stemmed field is: "break and enter".  Seems good.
However, when I query “broke and entered”, I get: “broke and enter”.  Thus, apparently, “broke” does not become “break” when the "english" stemmer is used.
Likewise, “broken and entered” becomes: “broken and enter”.  So, ES apparently does not change either “broke” or “broken” to “break” (which, according to this: [snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/diffs.txt), I guess explains why if this is what is used).

So, is there a way to specify a "known" stemmer that will accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be fulfilled by a Dictionary Stemmer, which does dictionary lookups for stemming words. Algorithmic stemmers stem without knowledge about the root words, they simply do it algorithmically. 
Look at Hunspell stemmer, think it will do the job: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hunspell.html

Comment: I followed the instructions for the Hunspell and it doesn't appear to do the job.  When I search for "broke and entered", I get (in the "explain" output): "description": "weight(doc.body.stemmed:\"broke and (entered enter)\" in 45) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"

Comment: Best part of the hunspell stemmer is, you can add your own rules to it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hunspell.html#hunspell-dictionary-format

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by adding entries into a *.dic file, such as: broke st:break.  Thanks for pointing me to hunspell.

Comment: Glad i could help :)